# How do I get the Promotions tab?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add in some coupon codes, but all the online tutorials talk about this Promotions tab in the menu which I do not have.

I am using Magento 1.9.3.1

[image]

I am also the admin with full rights.

Edit - Additional image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to system -> permissions -> roles

2) go to inside your current admin user role

3) go to role resources tab

4) check there Resource Access type is All or Custom? (better to set Resource Access type = ALL if you don't want to restrict admin user for show/hide menu)

5) if it's Custom then double check to Promotions permission should checked

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem to help others

Comment: Mine is set to 'All', but when I go to Custom, I can see the promotions tab there so it must be installed in the system. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: What do you mean? did you solved your issue or not? Option **All** And **Custom** both are of core structure's option, if you select the custom option then you have to select Promotions tab checked if you want to display in particular user, also other required option should be checked.

Comment: I just added an additional screenshot to my original post. Unfortunately it didn't solve it. You can see that it's already on All, but there is no Promotions menu item.